# Why does the Rust compiler not convert from a library error to my error using the From trait?

Tags: error-handling, rust

Given this crate referencing an error from another crate, I would normally write a `From` implementation to convert types.

```
use xladd::variant::{Variant, XLAddError};
use failure::Fail;
use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::convert::From;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
enum AARCError {
    #[fail(display = "F64 Conversion failure")]
    ExcelF64ConversionError,
    #[fail(display = "Bool Conversion failure")]
    ExcelBoolConversionError,
    #[fail(display = "Conversion failure")]
    ExcelStrConversionError,
}

impl From<XLAddError> for AARCError {
    fn from(err: XLAddError) -> Self {
        AARCError::ExcelF64ConversionError // Test for now
    }
}

pub fn normalize(array: Variant, min: Variant, max: Variant, scale: Variant) -> Result<Variant, AARCError> {
    let min: f64 = min.try_into().map_err(|e| AARCError::from(e))?;
    Ok(Variant::from_str("foo"))
}
```

But in this case I get an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `basic_stats::AARCError: std::convert::From<!>` is not satisfied
  --> src\basic_stats.rs:24:48
   |
24 |     let min: f64 = min.try_into().map_err(|e| AARCError::from(e))?;
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<!>` is not implemented for `basic_stats::AARCError`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <basic_stats::AARCError as std::convert::From<xladd::variant::XLAddError>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

I don't understand what the `From<!>` trait is and trying to implement something like that gives an error for unnamed types.

What should I be doing to enable Rust to convert the external crate's errors to my ones?

Comment: What are the crates (and versions thereof) that you are using? Please take a look at how to create a [mcve] and edit your question so that people can easily run your code and see the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand what the `From<!>` trait is and trying to implement something like that gives an error for unnamed types.

`!` is the ["never"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.never.html) or *uninhabited* type; the type that has no possible values.

If a `Result` has `!` for its error type, that means the operation cannot fail. It is impossible to convert from it to some other error type, because an error value cannot exist in the first place.

The never type is currently an experimental feature, requiring a nightly build of Rust. As such, it likely has a few rough edges, and it isn't as ergonomic as it could be. For example, I would expect the final feature to provide a blanket `From<T>` implementation for all types that implement `TryFrom<T>` with associated type `Error = !`. It should be made easy to not have to handle the error that can't happen.

To fix your immediate problem, you can map that error to `unreachable!()`. The only issue with that approach is forwards-compatibility - if the third party crate later introduces a reachable error then your code would have an unhandled error, and no compile-time error to protect you. That's probably a part of why `!` is not yet stabilised.

Comment: I believe this is only available in nightly as well, for reference.

Comment: @jhpratt I think OP must be using nightly to have gotten this far... I will add a note though.

Comment: I believe that as well. I'm just stating that for others that may come across it.